# Want to find a string with in all subdirectories in a folder

Tags: linux, zgrep

Suppose i'm in a folder

```
/data/
```

The folder data contains 10 other folders

```
/data/temp1
/data/temp2
/data/temp3
and so on
```

all of which have .gz files in them , i.e temp1 , temp2 , temp3 till temp10 all contain .gz files in them
I want to be able to locate a certain string lets suppose *ERROR:* within ALL files located in all 10 directories.

Is there a command that can help me do this ?

Comment: Do you just need to find .gz files that contain matches? Or do you need the matching line returned too?

Comment: just find .gz files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A basic find command should do:

`# find /data -name "*.gz" -exec zgrep "ERROR" {} \;`

There are a few alternate (and possibly more efficient) ways it could be formatted such as with `xargs`, but this will do the job, at least insofar as your question has asked.